# Selenium Python - drag and drop doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop

I am learning test automation and i have problem with drag and drop. I am testing on https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

Using this and nothing happen with those columns.

```
def test_drag_and_drop(self):
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop")
    column_a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='column-a']")
    column_b = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='column-b']")
    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(column_a, column_b).perform()
```

Comment: What's the error it outputs?

Comment: There is no error.
The item get's stuck to the cursor and that is it.
Until the browser closes.